# Melhor estruturação de um código orientado a objeto

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, estrutura-de-dados, arquitetura-de-software

Me deparei com um problema de estruturação de código e precisava de uma ajuda. Fiz um diagrama abaixo com dois métodos diferentes de estruturar um mesmo código (não pude criar o código ainda) e queria saber qual é melhor (ou se existe uma implementação ainda melhor):

- Em performance/eficiência (Busca, Remoção, Adição, Atualização);
- Em segurança;

A ideia é simples, defino uma superclasse Pessoa com duas Subclasses Professor e Estudante, e tenho uma Classe Classe(Matéria, em que cada matéria pode ter sua listagem diferente de alunos já que nem todos os alunos de uma turma estão necessariamente cadastrados nas mesmas matérias) que possui uma referência ao professor que leciona a mesma.

A grande diferença entre ambas é que, na segunda, a ArrayList é um atributo da classe, enquanto na primeira foi criada uma estrutura (pensei em TreeMap, ou existe estrutura mais adequada?) para armazenar acessar os dados. A ideia do TreeMap é armazenar referências para as matérias e as listagens de alunos respectivas.[image: diagrama]

Comment: Você representa coisas diferentes em ambos exemplo, no caso da direita, você possui um TreeMap que representa uma matéria, ele poderia ser um tipo abstrato de dado, uma nova classe, mas nesse caso, o que tu diz é, uma classe tem várias matérias, e cada matéria tem seus estudantes, algo parecido com um mestrado, cada um escolhe as matérias que quer cursar, no segundo caso, uma classe tem seus estudantes, algo parecido com ensino médio, você possui duas abstrações distintas nisso, primeiro estabeleça o que você quer representar, pois fiquei em dúvida quando fui criar um modelo performático.

Comment: Não não, acho que expressei errado. Quando digo classe, é como se fosse uma matéria mesmo. E cada matéria tem seus alunos cadastrados. A Treemap seria uma estrutura de dados pra armazenar referências para as diferentes matérias cadastradas e a listagem de alunos que estão cursando as mesmas. Vou editar o post

Comment: Outra dúvida quando pensamos em performance da aplicação é, você está pensando em usar frameworks? se sim, quais? ou quer trabalhar com o java puro?

Comment: O exemplo específico seria em Java puro, especificamente para entender (sem influência de frameworks) qual seria a diferença performática e de segurança entre possuir uma estrutura para manipular os dados, ou manipular eles diretamente através do acesso aos atributos da classe. Pode-se assumir que existiram centenas de matérias cadastradas, cada uma com sua listagem de alunos

Comment: Eu utilizaria um HashSet no lugar da TreeMap, iria ficar muito mais performático.

Comment: @Emanoel o Eu havia pensado em HashSet, mas a propriedade de ordenação natural do TreeMap faz muito sentido (na minha concepção) para uma lista de alunos. Vou ver se encontro alguns exemplos de comparação de performance entre as duas estruturas, sinceramente ambas mal são citadas na faculdade e estou estudando por fora, então tenho que correr atrás haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiramente, apenas como sugestão para facilitar o entendimento do seu modelo, sugiro que chame sua classe de "Disciplina". Chamar de "Classe" é confuso porque todas elas são classes (em termos de OO) e "Matéria" na verdade são os assuntos abordados em uma disciplina.

Avaliando os cenários que você propôs:

1) Caso você use uma lista de **Disciplinas** como atributo da classe **Estudante**, você delega à classe Estudante qualquer alteração em suas Disciplinas. Nesse caso, você estaria aplicando o conceito de **Encapsulamento**, ou seja, a responsabilidade por conhecer os detalhes da implementação estaria oculta na classe Estudante.

Responda às seguintes perguntas para saber se a abordagem acima atende ao seu caso de uso:

- Quais são as regras de negócio aplicáveis ao caso de uso? Por exemplo, há um número mínimo/máximo de estudantes por disciplina, ou um número mínimo/máximo de disciplinas por estudante?
- Há disciplinas que possuem outras como predecessoras, sendo preciso consultar se aquele Estudante já cursou todas as predecessoras antes de matricula-lo?

Nesses exemplos, os métodos da classe Estudante seriam responsáveis por esse controle, independente de que outra classe estiver alterando as disciplinas para aquele estudante.

Portanto, lembre-se que os objetos têm dados (atributos) e comportamento (métodos), sendo esse último a principal diferença entre os objetos e estruturas de dados simples.

Um modelo no qual as classes de domínio apenas guardam seus atributos e referências umas às outras e todos os processos ocorrem fora dessas classes, é um *anti-pattern* conhecido como [*Anemic Domain Model*](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html).

Logo, não adianta apenas esconder a lista de disciplinas dentro da classe Estudante e construir diversas outras classes para manipular as alterações dessa lista, pois você estaria quebrando o encapsulamento.

Com relação à performance, é você quem decide, a cada momento, se deve construir um objeto Estudante com todas as Disciplinas (*Eager Fetch*), ou apenas com os dados básicos do Estudante (*Lazy Load*). Na verdade, não consigo imaginar uma instituição de ensino onde o número de estudantes ativos e de disciplinas seja tão grande a ponto de impactar a performance da aplicação. Caso você venha a ter alguma lentidão, provavelmente será por outro motivo, como código não otimizado, erro na configuração do servidor, hardware subdimensionado etc.

2) Caso você use uma estrutura de dados, como um TreeMap, relacionando listas de Estudantes a cada objeto Disciplina, possivelmente você verá esse TreeMap sendo passado como parâmetro de um lado para outro em vários métodos. Todos esses métodos teriam que implementar os controles existentes na relação entre esses dois objetos, ou pior, seria preciso uma terceira classe, especialista em Estudantes e Disciplinas, só para isso.

Como uma de suas preocupações é com a segurança, como garantir que todas as partes do código que usam esse TreeMap vão obedecer todas as regras?

De que classe seria a responsabilidade de comparar os dados desse TreeMap com outros dados, por exemplo, outro TreeMap com as disciplinas predecessoras já cursadas por um Estudante?

Um critério que também pode te ajudar a tomar este tipo de decisão de *design* é verificar se a implementação proposta **faz sentido no mundo real**.

- Faz sentido um estudante saber em quantas disciplinas ele deve se inscrever? Ou saber que não pode se inscrever em mais de X disciplinas?
- Faz sentido um estudante saber responder que disciplinas ele cursa?
- Faz sentido um estudante pedir para sair de uma disciplina?
- Dada uma disciplina, faz sentido um estudante saber quem é o professor, **caso curse** aquela disciplina?

Comment: Muito interessante sua resposta, esclareceu bastante coisa. Achei importante o estudo das regras de negócio, não havia pensado exatamente em alguns pontos que você citou. Tenho que ficar mais atento. No caso, o que parece fazer sentido para mim é uma referência dupla, o Aluno possui uma lista de disciplinas que cursa, e a disciplina possui uma lista de alunos (para facilitar as consultas, já que os dados dificilmente seriam alterados)

Comment: Utilizando a informação que você citou e o fato de que o Aluno teria uma lista de Disciplinas que cursa, e a disciplina teria uma lista de alunos, uma boa implementação seria o aluno possuir métodos para manipulação de sua lista de disciplinas que está cursando (que é um atributo da classe Aluno), e a classe Disciplina prover a construção da lista com as chaves Disciplina/Alunos Cadastrados e cuidar de sua manipulação, incluindo a TreeMap Alunos/Disciplinas Previamente Cursadas, como métodos Estáticos? Não seria uma aplicação melhor da Separation of Concerns?

Comment: Na verdade eu não havia pensado especificamente no caso da predecessora, isso realmente faz sentido como uma ArrayList<Disciplinas> de atributo da classe, a ideia que tinha imaginado era tornar a TreeMap com a listagem de disciplinas e alunos cadastrados nelas como Static, pois não faz sentido instanciar  uma disciplina pra verificar isso, e realizar algo similar com a TreeMap de Alunos/Disciplinas Previamente Cursadas *Por esse aluno*. Mas agora que parei para pensar, isso faz mais sentido como um atributo ArrayList<Disciplinas> na própria classe do aluno pra encapsular a informação/segurança

Comment: Entendi, é exatamente o que eu estava imaginando depois das sugestões. Obrigado pela força! :D

Answer (score 1):

A diferença em relação a estas estruturas de dados:

### Lista

- Inserção: na inserção em uma lista não ordenada, o novo item da lista será inserido após o ultimo objeto da lista
- Remoção: Na remoção em uma lista não ordenada, para remover um item, será necessário percorrer a lista até achar o item que deseja remover, se a lista tiver 100 itens, você irá percorrer os 100 itens caso o item desejado seja o último.
- Atualização: Na atualização em uma lista não ordenada, para remover um item, será necessário percorrer a lista até achar o item que deseja atualizar
- Busca: A busca também irá percorrer toda a lista até encontrar o item

### Árvore

- Inserção: na inserção em uma árvore, a árvore pode executar seu balanceamento, o que pode ser custoso.
- Remoção: na remoção em uma árvore, a árvore pode executar também o seu balanceamento.
- Atualização: Para encontrar um item em uma árvore é mais performático, pois se a árvore possuir 05 níveis, será no máximo 05 interações para encontrar o seu objeto.
- Busca: A busca em uma árvore é performática, igualmente no caso acima.

Em relação a segurança, não compreendo como a estrutura de dados escolhida poderia afetar tal item.

Em relação a performance, em pequenos datasets a diferença de performance é irrelevante. Vai depender muito do seu uso, você deve compreender qual uso será melhor aproveitado pela sua aplicação.
Se você apenas adicionar elementos nesta estrutura, sem consultas, vá de lista, será mais robusto para a sua aplicação.
Se você realizar muitas atualizações, e buscas, com poucas inserções e remoções, vá de árvore.

### Orientação a Objetos

Seguindo o princípio da Orientação a Objetos, o ideal é construir uma classe Matéria, pois assim você obtém uma maior coesão do seu código.

Comment: A diferença entre Árvore e Lista está clara, mas no caso específico esta não era a questão. A questão é: Ter uma ArrayList<Estudantes> acoplada em cada Classe Matéria (portanto, como um atributo da classe Matéria) ou não ter essa informação dentro da classe Matéria, mas armazenar ela como um par chave/valor em uma estrutura externa. Qual dos dois torna a aplicação mais performática e robusta, se a maior parte da movimentação de dados vai ser Consultas/Atualizações, e não Remoção/Adição de dados? Consultar uma estrutura (portanto, ter que buscar onde da estrutura estão os dados) é mais custoso?